# MVC How to Duplicate forms based on the DropDownList value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question regarding MVC, I am still quite new to this framework, previously work on ASP.NET Web Form.

My Question is in my web page or View, I am trying to display a DropDownList from 1 to 2 which user can select, and based on their selection display/populate/duplicate a Name TextBox. Something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="numOfPPl" name="numOfPpl">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
</select>

if (numOfppl == 1)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Application"))
```

I am just wondering how do I retrieve the options chosen ?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to use the `@Html.DropDownList` helper inside the form and then check the selected value in your controller.

Comment: The thing you are trying to accomplish with your code in Razor View is impossible because Razor View is rendered at server side. See the answer below and use JavaScript instead of C# in a Razor View

Comment: @S.Akbari Hi, thanks for the reply, but how do I add value 1 and 2 into the list? I assume the List must taken value from certain location right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since that logic will be performed at a client's side you should use JavaScript.
You'll need to add an event listener to `select #numOfPPl` that will listen for `change` event and set TextBox's value.
This example shows how to do that using jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('select#numOfPPl').on('change', function() {
        $('input#myTextBox').val(this.value);
    });
});
```